# Query optimization to avoid long running time

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select tlb.player_id,device_gcm_id
from st_pms_transaction_master ps
right join (
    SELECT pm.player_id,device_gcm_id,device_version
    FROM st_pms_player_device_version_master dvm
    INNER JOIN st_pms_player_master pm ON dvm.player_id=pm.player_id
    inner join st_pms_device_master device on device.device_id=dvm.device_id  
    WHERE pm.status='ACTIVE'  AND device_gcm_id IS NOT NULL) tlb
on ps.player_id=tlb.player_id where transaction_date <= '2018-02-27 00:00:00.0' and tlb.player_id not in (
    select player_id
    from st_pms_transaction_master
    where transaction_date >= '2018-02-27 00:00:00.0'
   , group by player_id)
group by ps.player_id
```

Actually the query is right but I want to optimize it as it's taking long time to execute like 10 minutes. So I'm working on it but need some suggestions for an easy go!

Comment: I don't follow: is there a specific problem you are facing or are you searching for someone to rewrite the query for you?

Comment: The SQL `explain ...`  and indices must be checked. Adding some index might help. As you have several group-by's one could maintain a redundant grouping table (a computational overhead at other places).

Comment: I don't want anyone to rewrite the query but i want suggestions to make it better @giorgiga. So i can rewrite the query.

Comment: Varunj, this question is just throwing your problem at others in hope that they do your work for you. Read some introductory material on how queries are executed (google is your friend), experiment and try to identify *why* your query doesn't execute as swiftly as you expect. If during this process you bang your head on something difficult/unexpected/unclear, then feel free to ask and rest assure people will help out (also, after a bit of research you'll understand what relevant info must be included in such questions)

Comment: The query, as written, has at least one syntax error (the comma before `group by`).  If returning a syntax error is the desired behavior, you definitely don't need to wait 10 minutes for that.